# Why does this mod_rewrite expression not append the existing query string correctly?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, parameters

I'm a real newbie regarding mod_rewrite so please don't laugh. I am using this tool for testing: http://civilolydnad.se/projects/rewriterule/

Basically I want to rewrite

```
http://hostname/spanish/whatever/
```

into

```
http://hostname/whatever/?lang=es
```

Here's the best I could come up with:

```
RewriteRule ^spanish/(.*)$ $1?lang=es [QSA,L,NC]
```

which seems to work **except** when the requested page already has parameters. In that case

```
http://hostname/spanish/gallery/photos/?page=2
```

gets rewritten as

```
http://hostname/spanish/gallery/photos/?page=2?lang=es
```

Can anyone help this confused newbie? Thank you very much.

Comment: While the *tool* gives that result, what does the actual *web server* give?

Comment: Ignacio makes a good point. I suspect if you try this in Apache it will actually do what you want.

Comment: I've also used that tool and it is very useful, but it isn't 100% perfect.  The Apache docs state your rule should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! It seems the tool mislead me -- I feel a bit better about myself now! I tested it on my machine and it works great. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the tool is misleading, because the rule was proven to be correct, as written, when used on a real server environment. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should help.

```
# Remove query strings from URL
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /.*\;.*\ HTTP/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteRule .* http://yourdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
```